# Как импортировать записи wp_forms?

Tags: база-данных, администрирование, worpdress

Существует сайт на `wordpress` и его зеркало. Зеркало является полной копией сайта, но доступно по другому url. Создано на случай "отвала" основного сайта. У каждого сайта своя БД. Основной сайт(и БД) и зеркало(и БД) лежат на разных хостингах.
На основном сайте работает форма обратной связи `wp_forms` и собирает записи в БД.

C момента создания зеркала основной сайт собирал записи, значит в БД зеркала нет последних записей с `wp_forms` и моя цель перенести недостающие записи из `wp_forms` с основного сайта на зеркало.

Конечно, можно с помощью экспорта записей в самом плагине `wp_forms` сгенерировать файл с расширением `csv` и скачать его. Так я и сделал. Но проблема в том, что `wp_forms` умеет только в импорт самих форм, но не записей. Т.е. в плагине есть вкладка импорт, но там можно импортировать сами формы на сайт, но не записи этих форм.

Дальше я начал искать плагины для импорта записей в `wordpress`, но они предназначены для импорта записей `wordpress`, но не записей `wp_forms` и с их помощью корректно добавить новые записи `wp_forms` на зеркало не удалось.

**Вопрос:** Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли плагин для `wordpress` или аддон для `wp_forms`, который может корректно добавить недостающие записи из `wp_forms` на сайт? Если такого плагина нет, то как без плагина это можно сделать?

**Дополнительная информация:**
Синхронизация самих сайтов не налажена никак, она отсутствует.
Зеркало поднято с помощью специального плагина для wp - `Duplicator`.
Зеркало не должно работать до тех пор, пока не упадет основной сайт.
Зеркало закрыто через htaccess.

**P.S.** Думаю, в настоящий момент моих знаний и времени недостаточно, чтобы потянуть автоматическую репликацию БД и синхронизацию сайтов, я лишь ищу решение, которое здесь и сейчас позволит малой кровью добавлять новые записи `wp_forms` на зеркало с определенной периодичностью. И пока лучше ничего не придумал, как идти в `phpMyAdmin` основного сайта, делать экспорт нужных таблиц, потом идти в `phpMyAdmin` зеркала и импортировать нужные таблицы.

Comment: зачем искать плагин, если можно тупо перенести [две таблицы](https://wpforms.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/database-table.jpg) из БД?  можно добавить скрипт в crontab чтобы делал синхронизацию периодически. Если записей меньше 16 миллионов, можно каждый раз пересоздавать таблицы с ноля.

Comment: @DiD, основной сайт(и БД) и зеркало(и БД) лежат на разных хостингах, есть еще таблица wp_wpforms_entry_fields, она тоже нужна.

Comment: так в чем дело? 1. скрипт экспорта нужных таблиц из основной бд в файлы на основном сайте. 2. скрипт копирования файлов с основного сайта на зеркало. 3. скрипт импорта скопированных файлов в бд зеркала. 4. реализовать условие для запуска экспорта\импорта (3-х скриптов из пред. пунктов)

Comment: @Zombotron, не имею представления, насколько сложны будут в реализации шаги, описанные вами, но в любом случае полезные мысли, я посмотрю в эту сторону.

Comment: Вот странно... как веб-сервер, так зеркалим, а как его БД, так колхозим. Это что, принципиальный такой подход, что ли? Не знаю, как там налажена синхронизация самих сайтов, а базы данных явно ждут нормальной мастер-мастер репликации.

Comment: @Akina Ага. Может сразу кластеризацию замутить? Что-то мне подсказывает, что "зеркало" - это просто копия архива файлов, развернутого вручную. И сайты скорее всего там на обычных шаред-хостиингах. Вполне возможно, что сайт на "зеркале" не полнофункциональный ресурс, работающий в режиме замещения, а просто копия, не удивлюсь даже, если доступная по другому адресу.

Comment: @Zombotron А какая разница-то? второй хостинг всё одно есть - ну так пусть работает, а не ковыряет в носе, падения основного сайта ожидаючи.

Comment: @Akina Судя по всему, ТС как раз на пути к этому. )

Comment: Была у одного знакомого ситуация. Вроде подход серьёзный mssql, kubernetes, синхронизация, файловый траф распределен по cdn. Однажды во время корпоратива, товарищ вспомнил, что не выложил толи какую-то анимацию на SVG толи фотки... Короче, залил на прод, а там совсем не та картинка. В спешке решил удалить, и удалил всю ноду. Синхронизация отработала более чем успешно. Все возможные копии сайта сделали самоликвидацию вслед за центральным продом. Даже в бакапах почистился "мусор". Спасла только копия сайта двухнедельной давности, которую чел вручную сделал для себя и хранил на домашнем компе.

Comment: @DiD Да, автосинхронизация - страшная вещь. )) А по поводу первого вашего коммента - если записей много и есть индексы, кроме автоинкремента, то быстрее будет так: создать таблицу с временным именем `name_tmp` без индексов, добавить все строки, проставить индексы, удалить таблицу  `name`, переименовать  `name_tmp` в  `name`, Вообще, наиболее безопасно ничего не удалять, а только помечать, как удаленное и синхронизировать в рантайме по апи.

Comment: @Zombotron Развертка бакапа - процесс интересный и долгий, пока сервер работает на износ, есть время на раздумья. Можно делать с временной таблицей, можно удалить индексы на время развертки, правда обычно до этого не доходит. В рядовых случаях хватает режимов простой блокировки таблицы и единой транзакции. Если в БД таблицы MyISAM, их проще бакапить/восстанавливать файлами `.frm`, `.myd` и `.myi`. Но MyISAM итак реактивные, уж их обработкой сервер нагрузить невозможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дамп и разворачивание дампа можно сделать одной строкой на кроне:

```
mysqldump -u[SOURCE_USER] -p[SOURCE_PASSWORD] --ignore-table=... --ignore-table=... [SOURCE_DATABASE] | mysql -h[TARGET_HOST]-u[TARGET_USER] -p[TARGET_PASSWORD] [TARGET_DATABASE]
```

Comment: Это если сайт(ы) на vps или хостинг поддерживает ssh команды.

Comment: кроном на любом шаред хостинге можно управлять

Comment: Может уже и на любом. я давно этим не интересовался. Лет 5 назад мне попадались такие, где php сценарии только можно было запускать.

Answer (score 2):

Функция экспорта дампа всей БД.

```
function create_dump(){
    $dbh = mysqli_init();
    $dbh->real_connect($_DB_HOST, $_DB_USER, $_DB_PASSWORD, $_DB_NAME, $port, $socket, $flags);
    if($_DB_CHARSET) $dbh->set_charset($_DB_CHARSET);

    $dump_dir = "../zip"; // директория, куда будем сохранять резервную копию БД
    $dump_name = 'dump.sql'; //имя файла
    $insert_records = 50; //записей в одном INSERT
    $res = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLES");
    $fp = fopen($dump_dir."/".$dump_name, "w");
    while($table = $res->fetch_row()){
        $query="";
        if($fp){
            $res1 = $dbh->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE ".$table[0]);
            $row1 = $res1->fetch_row();
            $query="\nDROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$table[0]."`;\n".$row1[1].";\n";
            fwrite($fp, $query); 
            $query="";
            $r_ins = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$table[0].'`');
            if($r_ins->num_rows > 0){
                $query_ins = "\nINSERT INTO `".$table[0]."` VALUES ";
                fwrite($fp, $query_ins);
                $i=1;
                while($row = $r_ins->fetch_row()){
                    $query="";
                    foreach($row as $field){
                        if ( is_null($field) )$field = "NULL";
                        else $field = "'".$dbh->real_escape_string( $field )."'";
                        if ( $query == "" ) $query = $field;
                        else $query = $query.', '.$field;
                    }
                    if($i>$insert_records){
                                    $query_ins = ";\nINSERT INTO `".$table[0]."` VALUES ";
                                    fwrite($fp, $query_ins);
                                    $i=1;
                                    }
                    if($i==1){$q="(".$query.")";}else $q=",(".$query.")";
                    fwrite($fp, $q); $i++;
                }
                fwrite($fp, ";\n");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Функция импорта дампа всей бд:

```
function load_db_dump($file,$sqlserver,$user,$pass,$dest_db){
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($sqlserver, $user ,$pass,$dest_db);
    mysqli_query($mysqli,'SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
    /* 
    //drop tables
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"show tables"); // run the query and assign the result to $result
    if($result){
        while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result
            mysqli_query($mysqli,'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table[0]);
        }
    }
      */
    mysqli_query($mysqli,'SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
  
    $sql=mysqli_connect($sqlserver,$user,$pass,$dest_db);
    $a=file($file);
    foreach ($a as $n => $l) 
        if (substr($l,0,2)=='--')
            unset($a[$n]);
    $a=explode(";\n",implode("\n",$a));
    unset($a[count($a)-1]);
    foreach ($a as $q) 
        if ($q)
            if (!mysqli_query($sql,$q)) {return 0;}
    mysqli_close($sql);
    return 1; 
}
```

Загрузить файл дампа с одного сервера на другой по http, не упираясь в ограничения по памяти:

```
function server_q($url, $location, $file, $dest){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url.$location.$file);
    
    $res = fopen($dest, 'a+');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE,    $res);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($res);
}
```

Проверку для экспорта определенных таблиц вставить, я думаю, не составит труда.

Ну и вставить в индексный файл (или в крон) запуск создания дампа на осн. сервере раз в сутки, например.

После создания дампа отправить запрос на зеркало для запуска скрипта скачивания только что созданных файлов.

После скачивания файлов запустить сприпт импортатолько что скаченных файлов в бд зеркала.

Функции для скриптов взял из рабочего проекта. Только кое что повырезал, так что может где-то ошибки будут. (пока нет времени проверить. попробуйте сами для начала, а там, если что, помогу)

Comment: Как поведёт себя этот код, если настройки серверов различаются? особенно если на целевом сервере SQL Mode зажата по полной программе, а на исходном - достаточно либеральна?

Comment: @Akina Это писалось не мной и не столько для зеркалирования, сколько для создания копии WP сайта с одного хостинга на другом. На большинстве шаред хостингах со стандартными настройками этих хостингов и WP оно работает. Я не претендую на правильность, универсальность и каноничность решения (сам я сделал бы принципиально не так), но судя по вопросу человеку нужно именно что-то подобное, а не заморочки с синхронизаций, балансировкой нагрузки, инкрементными\"декрементными" обновлениями, системой контроля версий и пр. Тупо бекапить данные с 1 на 2 на случай падения 1. Большего я в вопросе не вижу.